# Drop last rows of df based on string search

Tags: excel, pandas

I am importing from an Excel file and need to delete the last rows based on a string value.

In this case I need to end at the date in row 65.

the last (predictable) row will be the row that contains the string "Net Account" less 5 rows.

is it possible to select just the rows with the date format? Not sure which is best way to approach this?

```
60  2011-08-31 00:00:00     285085          0          0          0   
61  2011-09-30 00:00:00     273926          0          0          0   
62  2011-10-31 00:00:00     287235          0          0          0   
63  2011-11-30 00:00:00     284034          0          0          0   
64  2011-12-31 00:00:00     284974          0          0          0   
65  2012-01-31 00:00:00     294412          0          0          0   
66                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
67                   58     222613     378197      25000      33350   
68                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
69                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
70     Net Account Loss        NaN        NaN     -92135        NaN   
71                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: sorry i did not get what you exactly want.

Comment: show me proper data and expected data .

Answer (score 1):

If need remove all rows where is no datetime in first column use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - it return `NaT` for not datetime, create mask by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').notnull()
df = df[mask]
print (df)
                   date         a    b    c    d
60  2011-08-31 00:00:00  285085.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
61  2011-09-30 00:00:00  273926.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
62  2011-10-31 00:00:00  287235.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
63  2011-11-30 00:00:00  284034.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
64  2011-12-31 00:00:00  284974.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
65  2012-01-31 00:00:00  294412.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```